# Scaling of features produces all NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have the following pandas data frame `df`:

```
COL1  COL2     COL3
0.0   -258.0   A
0.0   -262.2   A
0.0   -210.0   C
0.0   -84.0    B
0.0   -237.0   A
0.0   -277.2   B
0.0   -273.0   A
0.0   15.0     B
0.0   21.0     C
0.0   -61.8    C
```

I want to apply `RobustScaler` to numerical features `COL1` and `COL2`:

```
scaler = preprocessing.RobustScaler(quantile_range = (0.0,0.9))
scaler.fit(df_subset[["COL1","COL2"]])
df[["COL1","COL2"]] = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(df[["COL1","COL2"]]), columns=["COL1","COL2"])
```

However, when I check the result, I see all `NaN` values in `COL1` and `COL2`:

```
df[["COL1","COL2"]]

NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are not missing something else? Because I've run your code with your dataset and it worked well.

Before Scaler

```
  COL1    COL2 COL3
0  0.0  -258.0    A
1  0.0  -262.2    A
2  0.0  -210.0    C
3  0.0   -84.0    B
4  0.0  -237.0    A
5  0.0  -277.2    B
6  0.0  -273.0    A
7  0.0    15.0    B
8  0.0    21.0    C
9  0.0   -61.8    C
```

The code I've run:

```
scaler = preprocessing.RobustScaler(quantile_range=(0.0, 0.9))
scaler.fit(df[["COL1", "COL2"]])
df[["COL1", "COL2"]] = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(df[["COL1", "COL2"]]), columns=["COL1", "COL2"])
```

Output

```
   COL1        COL2 COL3
0   0.0 -101.410935    A
1   0.0 -113.756614    A
2   0.0   39.682540    C
3   0.0  410.052910    B
4   0.0  -39.682540    A
5   0.0 -157.848325    B
6   0.0 -145.502646    A
7   0.0  701.058201    B
8   0.0  718.694885    C
9   0.0  475.308642    C
```

Update

```
scaler = preprocessing.RobustScaler(quantile_range=(0.0, 0.9))
scaler.fit(df[['COL1', 'COL2']])
df[['COL1', 'COL2']] = scaler.transform(df[['COL1', 'COL2']])
print(df[['COL1', 'COL2']])
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that I don't miss anything. Please see screenshots from Databricks that I just added to the thread (column names are different).

Comment: Is there any way to debug what is happening?

Comment: In my case sklearn version is 0.22.1 and pandas version is 1.0.0

Comment: Actually, when I created `df` manually, then `RobusteScaler` started working. So, it is probably the issue of data. But I have only 10 rows in data that I showed in my question. I checked `dtypes` and I see `float64`. No nans in the input data. I don't understand why this issue happens.

Comment: If you can provide example of data I can help more.

Comment: Thanks. I uploaded a dataset (10 rows x N columns) here: https://file.io/8hY8Ih
I am interested in columns "HOLDING_SEC" and "ADDITIONAL_ASMA_40".

Comment: I think there is problem with download link I get 404 not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208773/discussion-between-talatccan-and-fluxy).